# Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'. Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'

Tags: angular

I have reproduced the issue on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iah7up) with minimal code.

Step 1: Click on the text

Step 2: Focus on the text field

Step 3: Type enter and check the console for this error

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has
>   changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ng-untouched: true'.
>   Current value: 'ng-untouched: false'.

Comment: this is a common error in angular, you have to do some lectures to understand what's happening https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4 and https://medium.com/better-programming/expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-in-angular-what-why-and-how-to-fix-it-c6bdc0b22787

Comment: Otherwise, Why you creating a Directive and calling your component after ? why you do not handling all that in your component ? You can use fromEvent for keydown like `switchMapTo(merge(clickOutside$, fromEvent(this.element, 'keydown').pipe(filter(e => e.keyCode === 13))))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to manually trigger change detection in the directive using the `detectChanges()` method of the `ChangeDetectorRef`

Modify `editable-on-enter-inplace.directive.ts` like this:

`import { Directive,HostListener ,ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';`

```
 constructor(private editable: EditableInplaceComponent,private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  @HostListener('keyup.enter')
  onEnter() {
    this.editable.toViewMode();
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering why this error comes out, and for a simple answer it was related to calling the same import element several times in different components and also in the `app.module.ts.

The **error** comes when following a modal example [Modal Example using ng-bootstrap](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-bootstrap-modal-tutorial-by-example/).

I solved the issue by simply calling it within a service, for using it along all the application.

Calling In `app.module.ts`.

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Calling In `app.mycomponent.ts`.

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

To **resume**, the error pop when calling the import in different components of my application.

Comment: could you please expand on your answer? I also have the same problem with ngbModal, but your answer only gives examples of the same import.