# Expression changed after ithas been checked Error

Tags: angular

In my angular App. I am implementing checkboxes using ngmodel. whhen i implement it i get this error. Please guide me on resolving it.

Error

```
core.js:5873 ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'ng-untouched': 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

HTML

```
  <div class="row"> 
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" (ngModelChange)="selectAll(selectedAll);">
      </div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56891143/error-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-previous-value-ng-untouche dose this is your ans?

Comment: In dev mode, the change detection lifecycle runs twice where it would run once in prod. After the second run, angular checks to see if the outcome of the first run matches the outcome of the second run, and provides this warning if there are differences. It can be an alert that you have a change detection problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **[(ngModel)]** you don't have to use **(ngModelChange)** event.

Html code

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" (ngModelChange)="selectAll($event)">
```

ts code

```
export class AppComponent  {
  
  selectedAll = false;

  selectAll(value: boolean) {
    console.log('check', value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change `(ngModelChange)="myFn()"` to `(change)="myFn()"`

```
  <div class="row"> 
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selectedAll" (change)="selectAll(selectedAll)">
  </div>
```